# Crystal Reports, image not displayed in c# report viewer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report that requires a different image to be loaded whenever a new report is printed. My entire report loads and displays just fine except for the Picture object. I'm not using a dataset and I'm not loading from a database. I set all the fields manually in my application. In the report designer I set an OLE Picture with a hyper link to a file. The file URL is loaded from a parameter field that points to the image to be loaded.

When I view my report in the c# crystal reports viewer my report looks fine except the image doesn't change. It continues to show the placeholder image I had set. When I click on the image in the report viewer, it loads the windows image viewer with the correct image. I hope someone will be able to help with this. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think clicking on a picture in a crystal report normally launches the image in your default associated application. Have you set the ole object's hyperlink attribute by mistake? (instead of the graphic location attribute).